# Boot camp network adapter not working?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, driver

I run windows 7 in boot camp. I downloaded the support software. How do I install the support software on windows? The computer won't recognize my USB. For some reason the graphics and the track pad and keyboard works.

IMPORTANT NOTE:The latest support software are not signed. I used a slightly older version.

Comment: The computer won't recognize the USB. It works on other devices. I have the support software.

Comment: At minimum we need to know what Mac model, underlying macOS, version of bootcamp, where you got the 'support software' from...